# BCP Syntax issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

All, I'm trying to write a query that I can run daily from a batch file on a SQL server 2008 instance.

I've never used BCP before but after looking at some examples online, I've tried to create a real basic query to test the process & permissions on the machine before I look to widen the select query to the required dataset.

I'm using:

```
 bcp    
"SELECT manifest_dt from EasyShip_050300.airwaybills"
queryout C:\Shares\DHL-EXPORT-TEST\file.txt -SGRENSON-CARRIER\DHLEASYSHIP -c -T
```

It appears to match nearly every example I can find online but everytime I execute this query I receive the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.
```

If anybody has any pointers it would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be `-SGRENSON-CARRIER\DHLEASYSHIP` have you tried with a servername without -  or using [ ] around it?

Comment: As Dan Guzman suggests, try running `bcp` from a command window, rather than from an SSMS query window.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should have the output file path in speech marks also, something like this;

```
 bcp    
"SELECT manifest_dt from EasyShip_050300.airwaybills"
queryout "C:\Shares\DHL-EXPORT-TEST\file.txt" -S GRENSON-CARRIER\DHLEASYSHIP -c -T
```

Also, put a space after your -S server declaration to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let me reply with two generic commands that I know to work in my environment (using trusted connection). See if they work on yours too, and work from there:

```
-- default row separator, column separator
DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(8000);
SET @stmt=
    'BCP '+
    '"SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" '+
    'QUERYOUT "C:\Temp\information_schema.txt" '+
    '-c -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME();
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt;

-- comma separated:
DECLARE @stmt_c VARCHAR(8000);
SET @stmt_c=
    'BCP '+
    '"SELECT*FROM '+QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" '+
    'QUERYOUT "C:\Temp\information_schema.csv" '+
    '-c -t, -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt_c;
```

If they work, `SELECT @stmt_c; SELECT @stmt;` and see how they are formed. Then see what the difference is with your commands.

Answer (score 0):

BCP is a command-line utility so you need to run it from a command-prompt instead of a SQL query window.

Comment: Not necessarily, You can run it with xp_cmdshell from within SSMS no problem. I had to do it recently for a work project.

Comment: @RichBenner - what Dan has noticed that the other answers miss is that the OP is getting a database engine error message; this means that the poster is attempting to run `bcp` from SSMS without using `xp_cmdshell` (or `SQLCMD` mode)

Comment: That is correct I was trying it in a query window initially but now I'm trying PowerShell instead. Error Messages are different now so I'm hopefully getting somewhere.